# Google map polyline with shadow

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I recently found an example which uses fusiontablelayer to show routes on a map and I wonder how could I style my normal polylines to have shadows like these: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/cycletrails.html Those looks really, really nice and I cant find an solution to do it with my polylines. (example of polyline without shadow: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple)

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_polyline-simple_shadow.html

(put a thicker transparent polyline under yours, looks like what I see them doing)

You could probably get the same effect the same way by using a KmlLayer or a FusionTablesLayer, rather than native Google Maps API v3 Polylines.

Code:

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
      new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
  var flightPathShadow = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeOpacity: 0.1,
    strokeWeight: 10
  });

  flightPathShadow.setMap(map);

  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Those trails are painted on custom tiles, for example:

http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US&lyrs=ft%3A132848|h%3Afalse|s%3Aselect%2520geom%2520from%2520132848%2520where%2520distance%2520%253C%252092&x=83&y=199&z=9&w=256&h=256&source=apiv3&token=125180

Comment: yes, it seems that they are but how does this will help me to solve my problem?

Comment: It doesn't, it just shows you how they've done it. With custom tiles you can make things look any way you want, but I understand that you want something served for you on a silver platter. I'm sorry, I don't do that.